# Discord.js не меняет название канала

Tags: javascript, discord-api, discord

Идея бота в дискорде такова, что при включении он меняет название голосового канала на количество участников на сервере, но он этого почему то не делает вот код:

```
bot.on('ready', ()  => {
let myGuild = bot.guilds.get("593425257096937473");
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.get("650447242381099018");
memberCountChannel.setName("Количество челов:"+ memberCount)
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: а какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: У вас используются разные переменные в 1-й и 2-й строках, вы подписываетесь на событие у объекта `bot`, а гильдии пытаетесь брать из `client`, так и задумано?

Comment: Ошибок никаких не выдает, а ```client.guilds.get ```уже заметил, заменил, но все равно не работает

Comment: А вы делаете bot.login с правильным токеном? и ещё событие ready происходит только когда вы запускаете бота, но потом если кто-то пришел/ушел название обновляться не будет, возможно нужно использовать, что-то другое, список всех: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

Comment: А ещё лучше подключиться дебагером и посмотреть, что именно не работает

Comment: Сам бот живой, работает, на другие команды откликается, насчёт того, что кто то ушел и пришел, я знаю, сначала хотел проверить, а оно не работает, а насчёт дебагера, где можно? Я просто никогда не пользовался

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален

Answer (score 1):

Я маленько изменил ваш код, так же bot на client

Вот код:

```
    client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
    let myGuild = client.guilds.get("616697847261298688");
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.get("664571882766467082");
    memberCountChannel.setName("Количество челов: "+ memberCount)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Чуть позже сделаю, чтоб он создавал канал, настраивая, чтоб никто не подключался

P.s гильдия и канал мой

Comment: Я маленько его изменил, если вам надо изменить кол-во времени, раз в которое оно будет обновляться, то 1000=1 сек.